# How should i pass a localStream object as an argument to an rtcpeerconnection addtrack method

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

I tried the code below

```
   localPeerConnection.addTrack(await localStream)
   remotePeerConnection.ontrack = () => {
      const remoteStreamVideoElement = document.querySelector("#remoteStreamVideoElement")
      remoteStreamVideoElement.srcObject = localStream
      remoteStreamVideoElement.onloadedmetadata = () => remoteStreamVideoElement.play()
   }
```

but it returned this error

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of RTCPeerConnection.addTrack does not implement interface MediaStreamTrack.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a track not a stream. The API reference and an example can be seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/addTrack).

```js
localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => localPeerConnection.addTrack(track));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
It solved it for me and also gave me a heads up for another bug unrelated to this

Comment: You might want to add the stream association as well, i.e. `.addTrack(track, localStream)`. That way the tracks will be grouped and surfaced in a stream with the same `stream.id` remotely.